# Immaterial vs nonmaterial which one to use?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, spelling

Is there a difference in using *immaterial* vs *nonmaterial*?
Do both of them have the same meaning ?

Besides, is it:

- non material
- nonmaterial
  or
- non-material?

I have found *nonmaterial* in the Merriam Webster dictionary.

Comment: kiyarash, we expect you to do a little basic research before asking a question.  if you look up the definitions of these words in a dictionary, what meanings do you find?

Comment: I have and and I couldn't find any differences that's why I am asking it . to make sure I am correct.

Comment: @kiyarash: *immaterial* is sometimes used in "philosophical" contexts with the *nonmaterial* (not made of matter, intangible, incorporeal ) sense, but it's mostly not used like that (partly because of possible confusion with the more common *not relevant, of no consequence* sense, no doubt).

Answer (score 1):

Saying something is "immaterial" means that it isn't relevant, or has no effect on a situation or eventual outcome.

> Due to the general disenfranchisement with the political system, Donald Trump's personal life was **immaterial.**
>
> So long as the band kept a beat, what they played was **immaterial.**

On the other hand, if an object is "nonmaterial," it does not physically exist.

> There are many **nonmaterial** goods exchanged on the market.

Though, I have to say, I don't think I've ever heard the word "nonmaterial," in my day-to-day life before, so I don't think it's common. On the other hand, maybe it's just me.

Comment: But immaterial also means not having a physical body or form. that was the meaning I was comparing to nonmaterial . Which to me does not seem different

Comment: @kiyarash Yes, it can also mean that, though I more often hear it being used as I described.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the definitions from the Oxford English Dictionary.

> [non-material](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/non-material)
>   1 Not having a physical or material form:
>  
>   "while e-texts are non-material, they must be read through a material object"
>   More example sentences
>   1.1 Involving or concerned with the needs of the mind, spirit, or intellect: 
>   "a public realm upholding non-material values"
>
> [immaterial](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/immaterial)
>   1 Unimportant under the circumstances; irrelevant
>  
>   "the difference in our ages is immaterial"
>   2 Philosophy Spiritual, rather than physical
>   "we have immaterial souls"

Both words have two meanings. In normal use, the first meanings are the most common, and the meanings are completely different. In the context of a philosophical or spiritual discussion, the second meanings are probably intended and they seem pretty similar.

According to the Oxford dictionary entry above, **non-material** is the correct spelling for British English, and [this entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/nonmaterial?q=non-material#nonmaterial__3) shows that it is **nonmaterial** for US English.

Comment: But according to the Merriam Webster    http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/nonmaterial       it's nonmaterial

Comment: @kiyarash, I have updated my answer